# UITextField move text left on start editing

Tags: ios, uitextfield

UITextField moves text to left on start editing. Is it possible not to move text? Text should be on the same place, when it was before editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have set TextAlignment to Center or Right.

Change this as

```
[yourTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This can be changed in the storyboard or xib as well.

Comment: Yes we can do this if we have used our textfield using XIB or storyboard. But if we have created programmatically then we need to do that manually.

Comment: Do you mean NSTextAlignmentLeft? You told that This is because you have set TextAlignment to Center or Right. Yes I set it to Center.

Comment: Yes use NSTextAlignmentLeft